# R: Artificial set generation

Tags: r, loops

I would like to generate the set with growing number of some representative.
In final I need a matrix or a data.frame, consisting of 100 rows containing `i` number of representative (in example it's `1`). But there is a following error. What is the trick? What I am missing?

```
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level

for(i in 1:100) {
    x <- c(rep(1,i),rep(100000,(2500-i)))
    return(x)
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `return` within a function. One solution is to create a matrix to store the results in, something like this:

```
R> m = matrix(0, ncol=100, nrow=2500)
R> 
R> for(i in 1:100) {
+   m[,i] = c(rep(1, i), rep(100000, (2500-i)))
+ }
```

should do the trick. Or using the `sapply` function:

```
m1 = sapply(1:100, function(i) c(rep(1, i), rep(100000,(2500-i))))
```

For info, your rep function can also be simplified to:

```
rep(c(1, 1000000), c(i, 2500-i))
```